# How to pass sqlite db values to controller

Tags: html, sqlite, web2py

Newbie in sqlite, web2py. Am trying to copy sqlite db contents to controller for another function.
My codes are these:
db.py

```
auth.define_tables(username=False, signature=False)

auth.settings.registration_requires_verification = False
auth.settings.registration_requires_approval = False
auth.settings.reset_password_requires_verification = True

db.define_table('chat',
        Field('me_from'),
        Field('me_body', 'text'),
```

default:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def index():
    chats.index(db)    
    body = db.chat.me_body()    
    rows = db(db.chat.me_body).select()#(orderby=~db.chat.me_body.created_on)    
    form1 = [body]    
    form5 = form1#.split()    
    name3 = ' '.join(form5)
```

I want t retrieve a string posted to db..

```
    chat.id chat.me_from    chat.me_body    chat.me_html
1                      
2       maurice         hi              <div class="m...
3       maurice         whats up        <div class="m...
4       maurice         where are you.  <div class="m...
5       maurice         3i5ejp[eoityjdt <div class="m...
6       maurice         how are you d...<div class="m...
7       maurice         britam          <div class="m...
```

From the table above, i want to retrieve from chat.me_body the posted words such as, 'hi', 'whats up', 'britam'... to default function. I instead keep getting the following errors:
If I use:
 `body = db.chat.me_body()`
the error is:

```
TypeError: 'Field' object is not callable
```

If I use:

```
`body = db.chat.me_body
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Field found
```

If I use rows:

```
rows = db(db.chat.me_body).select()
```

and

```
form1 = [rows]
```

the error is:

```
name3 = ' '.join(form5)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Rows found
```

I I'll appreciate your help

Comment: I strongly recommend you spend some time going through the web2py documentation (and probably brushing up on Python), as there are many errors and misconceptions in the code you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do a query to get records from the database is:

```
rows = db(db.chat).select(db.chat.me_body, db.chat.created_on,
                          orderby=~db.chat.created_on)
```

Note, `db(db.chat)` is shorthand for the query `db(db.chat.id != None)` (i.e., selection of all records in the table).

Then, to extract just the `me_body` field values into a list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
me_body_values = [r.me_body for r in rows]
```

Finally, you can join those values together:

```
name3 = ' '.join(me_body_values)
```